# Problem URLDecoding string from ASP to ASP.Net (international characters)

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have a string coming from an ASP page, and I'm trying to URL decode it and display it in an ASP.Net page.

`string str = @"%A0%A01stk.+%D8repynt+%3Cbr%3E%A0%A01stk.+Slipsn%E5l+%3Cbr%3E%3Cp%3E+Total+pris%3A+300";`

If you look at `%D8` it should be translated to the Norwegian character `Ø` when run through `HttpUtility.UrlDecode`. But it is not. Depending on what conversion I'm attempting it becomes different things, but never `Ø`. `%E5` should become `å`.

Here is some conversion code I've been trying out:

```
public static string Convert(string text)
{
    text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(text);
    var isoEncoder = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
    var utf8Encoder = new UTF8Encoding();

    byte[] txtBytes = isoEncoder.GetBytes(text);
    byte[] convertedBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(isoEncoder, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, txtBytes);

    return utf8Encoder.GetString(convertedBytes);
}
```

According to [Wikipedia article on Ø](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98#Computers):
*On Microsoft Windows, using the "United States-International" keyboard setting, it can be typed by holding down the Alt-Gr key and pressing "L". It can also be typed under any keyboard setting by holding down the [Alt] key while typing 0216 or 0248 on the numeric keypad, provided the system uses code page 1252 as system default. (Code page 1252 is a superset of ISO 8859-1, and 216 and 248 are the decimal equivalents of hexadecimal D8 and F8.)*

This seems to indicate that the input string is correctly formatted (%D8 = Ø).

Comment: What is the [character set](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for the ASP.NET page?

Comment: The response from server says `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8`. I also forgot to mention I can't make any major changes to web.config because its a common config file for lots of pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string str = @"%A0%A01stk.+%D8repynt+%3Cbr%3E%A0%A01stk.+Slipsn%E5l+%3Cbr%3E%3Cp%3E+Total+pris%3A+300";
        string decoded = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"))
```